# How to show that a non trivial exact functor is faithful.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a non trivial functor between two abelian categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.
Further, I know that $F$ is an exact functor. Now I want to show that $F$ is a faithful functor.
For that I need to show that the map $Hom(X,Y)\rightarrow Hom(F(X),F(Y))$ is injective. I don't know how to prove that this map is injective. Is there any other way to prove that the functor $F$ is faithful.

Comment: This is not true in general. Consider a trivial functor that maps all objects to $\{e\}$.

Comment: Adding non trivial won't help. For a still trivial example consider $F:\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{A}$ the functor $(A,A')\mapsto A$. For a less trivial example consider $F:\mathcal{A}b\to\mathcal{A}b$ the functor $F(A)=A\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ which is exact since $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat. Now $F(\mathbb{Z/2Z})=0$ so $Hom(\mathbb{Z/2Z,Z/2Z})\to Hom(F(\mathbb{Z/2Z}),F(\mathbb{Z/2Z}))$ is not injective.

Comment: @ Ronald if $F(A)\neq 0$ for $A\neq 0$, does it mean that $F$ is a faithful functor.